# is there any function i can use to seperate keys from list inside a list?

Tags: python-3.x

I am quite new to Python, but needs a help to seperate kyes from a list inside a list.

bellow code , gives  record as List, some of the values inside a list,

```
#file = open(filename, encoding="utf8")
import csv
from builtins import len
with open('Part1_Eng_Sumon1.csv', 'r',encoding="utf8") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    #reader = csv.DictReader(file)

    for row in reader:
        print (row)
        #print (type (row))
        #print(row[0:1])
        #p=(row[0:1])
        #print (p[0])
        #print (type (p))
       # r= (row[0].split())
        #print (r[1:2])
        #print (type(r))
        #lat=r[0]
        #lon=r[1:2]

        #print (lat)
        #print(lon)
        #print (len(lon))
       # print (type(lon))
        #print (lon[0:1])

        #print (lat,lon)
```

the out put is as bellow

```
['23.764333, 90.390119', 'BD', 'Dhaka', 'Dhaka', 'Dhaka', 'বিজয় সরনী - তেজগাঁও সংযোগ সড়ক', '111/3, Tejkunipara, Bijoy Sarani Link Road, Tajgaon, ঢাকা 1215', '', '', '', '', 'রায়হান মটরস্']
<class 'list'>
['23.764327, 90.389997', 'BD', 'Dhaka', 'Dhaka', 'Dhaka', 'বিজয় সরনী - তেজগাঁও সংযোগ সড়ক', 'Bijoy Sarani - Tejgaon Link Road, ঢাকা 1215', '', '', '', '', 'কার ক্লিনিক']
<class 'list'>
```

From the above out put, i need to seperate values as this, its same for every record from the list.

> lat=23.764333 lon= 90.390119'   road=বিজয় সরনী - তেজগাঁও সংযোগ সড়ক
>   road1= 111/3, Tejkunipara, Bijoy Sarani Link Road road3=রায়হান মটরস্

is there any way i can do ?

Thanks for the help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for Dictionary in Python.

the variable **row** in *for* loop is a list, which you can get values by index positions Ex:

```py
row = ['a','b','c']
print(row[0]) # 'a' , which is index zero (0)
print(row[1]) # 'b' , which is index one (1)
print(row[2]) # 'c' , which is index two (2)
```

I have noticed the latitude and longitude are in the same string separated by comma such as '12.2333, 14.3212323'. In that specific index you also need to split the string into two parts:

```
my_string = '1234, 5678'
example_list = my_string.split(',') # ['1234', '5678']

print(example_list[0]) #1234
print(example_list[1]) #5678
```

Assuming you have all values correctly in list, you can use an array of dictionaries like:

```py
    my_awesome_list = []
    for row in reader:
        first_data = row[0].split(',') # generate another list splitted the string by comma
        my_awesome_list.append({"lat": first_data[0].strip(), "lon":first_data[1].strip(), "road":row[2], "road1":row[3]})

    #Out of for loop
    print(my_awesome_list)

    '''
    [ 
      {
        "lat": 23.764333, 
        "lon":23.76434, 
        "road":'বিজয় সরনী - তেজগাঁও সংযোগ সড়ক', 
        "road1":'বিজয় সরনী - তেজগাঁও সংযোগ সড়ক'
      },
      {
        "lat": 23.784333, 
        "lon":23.76434, 
        "road":'ElisabethenStraße 13', 
        "road1":'Rua pedro valadares'
      },
      ...
    ]
    '''
```

To loop for in *my_awesome_list* you just need another for loop such as:

```
for address in my_awesome_list:
   print(address['lat'])
   print(address['lon'])
   print(address['road'])
   print(address['road1'])
```

Or you can directly access by index position as I explained:

```
print(my_awesome_list[0]['lat'])
print(my_awesome_list[0]['lon'])
print(my_awesome_list[0]['road'])
print(my_awesome_list[0]['road1'])
```

Comment: Henrique,
Thanks it gives the right value, i just need to figure out how to loop that my_awesome_list, but can you please tell me  bellow values are inside quote 
'23.764333, 90.390119'
how did it seperate by using row[0] and row[1] ?

Comment: I will update my answer what you are asking right now.

Comment: Henrique, Thanks again
With the recent changes,  the out put is like this 
[{'lat': '23.766599', 'lon': '90.418040', 'road': '202 West, Ulon Rd, ঢাকা 1219', 'road1': '3 Min Guitar School'}, {'lat': '23.766579', 'lon': '90.417859', 'road': '122 Ulon Rd, ঢাকা 1212', 'road1': 'Oddhay'}]

but when i try to pring ,

`
    print (address.lat)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'lat'
`

Comment: this one works,
for address in my_awesome_list:
        print (address.get('lat'))
        print (address.get('lon'))

Thanks for the help !!

Comment: You're welcome. You can access the attribute in the dictionary by address['lat'], address['lon']. I have updated by answer for help others.